# return text json from resource extension

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a resource extension where I want to return json as a response to the GET request.  I have JSON as text, not as a object tree.  I thought I could simply set the `output-type` in the `$context` map and then return the text in a document node, but it seems my content type gets changed to text/plain in the response headers.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace resource = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/json";

declare function get(
        $context as map:map,
        $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{

    let $output-type := map:put($context, "output-type", "application/json")
    return
        document {
            "{ ""name"": ""tj"" }"
        }
};
```

If I return a JSON object tree in the document node, i.e. wrapping the text in an `xdmp:unquote`, then it returns fine. BUT, what I want to do is to return the straight JSON without having to parse it.  I was trying to save having to do a XML to JSON transform on my responses that were expecting JSON. But having to to an xdmp:unparse or json:transform-to-json results in the same extra time, which I am trying to avoid.

Am I understanding what the `output-type` attribute is supposed to signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct key for a resource extension is output-types because your extension can return more than one document.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_84661

The key for a transform is output-type.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks.. I was looking at the documentation and assuming it was the same for all the different cases.